# git recover deleted remote branch

Tags: git, gitlab, branch

I was work on home PC and mistakenly removed branch before making merge with **dev**. Now I don't have access to my PC, but I really need those data.

```
git fsck --full --no-reflogs | grep commit
```

or

```
git reflog
```

does not help because commits were made on other PC.
Name of deleted branch I forget =(

Comment: If you didn't push your work to remote repo than it's only stored on your home PC.

Comment: I push commit to repo, but then i removed branch without merge with dev.

Answer (score 1):

If you pushed before you deleted it, and didn't delete the branch you pushed on the remote you pushed to, it will still be there. `git fetch`/`pull` that remote to get your branch.

If you didn't push, sorry - the data never left your home PC. You'll have to either SSH into your home PC or wait until you get home to run `git reflog`.